# Javascript in USQL; Is it a possible option in Azure data lake analytics?

Tags: azure, u-sql

We plan to follow Lambda architecture for our solution. The solution stack is on top of Azure. Azure data lake analytics used for batch processing, stream analytics is for online processing. We wanted to use same code and configuration is being used in both batch and streaming layer. Is there any option to use javascript in USQL with the help of .Net assemblies. Azure stream analytics is supports only javascript UDF. Has anyone tried similar options in azure stack?

Answer (score 0):

This probably wouldn't help much but wanted to share as if someone does have C# experience it would be an interesting approach.
https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2016/09/executing-javascript-inside-dot-net-core-using-javascript-services

in regards to specifically your issue, have you looked at the Node.js Module?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/data-lake-analytics?view=azure-node-latest